# Difficulty in aligning a set of results in an HTML section

Tags: html, css

I'm using span elements within section containers to build out a set of results that can be dynamically inserted by an external program.

The desired result should look something like this:
[image]

However, the result squashes all of the entries together, sticking their containers on the same line:
[image]

The title section is very simple, and consists of a section and five spans:

```
<section class="titleholder">
    <span id="htlabelHI">Entry Name</span>
    <span id="htlabelHI">Parameter</span>
    <span id="htlabelHI">Param in List</span>
    <span id="htlabelHI">Param in List2</span>
    <span id="htlabelHI">Param in List3</span>
</section>
```

The css is as follows:

```
.titleholder {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-align:center;
    border-top:solid;
    border-top-color:lightgray;
    border-top-width:thin;
    border-bottom:solid;
    border-bottom-color:lightgray;
    border-bottom-width:thin;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

The HTML for the results section is a little more complex:

```
<section class="results">    
    <div class="hazardResult">
        <span class="EntryName">11</span>
        <span class="Param">2</span>
        <span class="ParamList1">
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
            </ul>
        </span>
        <span class="ParamList2">
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
            </ul>
        </span>
        <span class="ParamList3">
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="hazardResult">
        <span class="EntryName">22</span>
        <span class="Param">2</span>
        <span class="ParamList1">
            <ul>
                <li>2</li>
            </ul>
        </span>
        <span class="ParamList2">
            <ul>
                <li>2</li>
            </ul>
        </span>
        <span class="ParamList3">
            <ul>
                <li>2</li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </div>
</section>
```

The CSS is not too dissimilar:

```
.results {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom:solid;
    border-bottom-color:lightgray;
    border-bottom-width:thin;
    height: 150px;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-top: 4px;    
    padding-left: 20px; 
    text-align:center;
}
```

I feel like I need to do something to distinguish the 'div' elements of each hazardResult, however setting the width does little more than move the elements around horizontally. The table has a maximum width of 900px.

I also tried individually setting the widths of each span, but this yielded no results.

What else can I try to even out the spacing? Bear in mind that the height of the div must adapt to the longest list.

Comment: Did you individually set the widths of each span and also set display:block?

Comment: @wazz Thanks, using 'display: block;' for the section, and 'display: flex;' for the individual divs worked